# Ruby: why isn't it possible to use #each directly as part of the arguments to a function?

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax

I'm just learning Ruby and there's one thing I don't understand. Ruby's been apparently created for simplicity and prototyping speed.

So, why if we want to - say - print the elements of an array can't we do something like:

```
puts array.each
```

And instead we have to do something like:

```
array.each{|element| puts "#{element}"}
```

It just seems unnecessarily way more complicated. Any insights?

Comment: Because each takes a block with what to do for each object. The inspect method, however, prints a representation of the object. This is hardly a language design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
puts array
```

Try it. How simple is that? :)

Comment: @Pensierinmusica: because that's how it is. Also `puts "#{y}"` can be simplified to `puts y`.